# MySQLi Bind Param with an array for IN

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to pass an array to `$stmt->bind_param` for as an IN variable. How can I do this?

```
$values = array('a','b','c','d');
$values = '"' . implode('","', $values) . '"';

$stmt->prepare('SELECT value1, value2 FROM table1 WHERE value3 IN (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $values);
```

I can't get it to work for the life of me. Any thoughts? The above code is just a sample.

Comment: Can you bind them individually?

Comment: I think it's the way you're imploding. MySQL isn't fond of the `"` (double quote). Did you try with a single quote?

Comment: @jason I did try it with single quotes, but no go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a scenario where doing it this way is inappropriate. You're constructing actual SQL (that's what the commas and quotes are), and passing it in as a parameter. It's basically evaluating to `value3 IN ('...')` where `...` is the entirety of `$values`.

Also that's a good call about the quotes. MySQL uses single quotes.

You'll need to either build the SQL using string concatenation alone, or use more than one parameter.

**EDIT**

As an example:

```
$values = array('a','b','c','d');
$values = "'" . implode("','", $values) . "'";
$stmt->prepare('SELECT value1, value2 FROM table1 WHERE value3 IN (' . $values . ')');
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide a little code sample or a link so I can learn more?

Comment: Thanks, do I need to be worried about SQL injection with this method? The `$values` in my real work is user generated.

Comment: @ATLChris, in that case, yes. You should pre-escape the values yourself with `mysqli->real_escape_string()` before inserting it directly into your query.

Comment: Please delete this answer. It still contains an SQL injection, which is only mentioned in the comments. This is too dangerous, and it has been like that for almost 9 years.

Comment: @RolandIllig it's not "injection" if none of the data comes from a user. If the coder trusts the inputs, this solution works fine. If not, the comments above yours already address the proper handling. Stop concern-trolling please.

Answer (score 2):

It *can* but **SHOULD NOT** be done, as it is code that is hard to maintain (read, understand, debug, change).

A way to do it would use dynamic variables to provide auto-referencable variables and using call_user_func_array to supply a dynamic amount of arguments to the callback/method `$stmt->bind_param()`.

```
<?php
$values = array('a','b','c','d');

$s = substr( str_repeat( ' , ?' , count( $values ) ) , 2 );
$stmt->prepare('SELECT value1, value2 FROM table1 WHERE value3 IN (' . $s . ')');
# OR array_map in case of different datatypes
$typeDefintions = str_repeat( 's' , count( $values ) );
$params = array( $typeDefinitions );
foreach ( $values as $k => $v ) {
    ${ 'varvar' . $k } = $v;
    $params[] = &${ 'varvar' . $k };# provide references
}
call_user_func_array( array( $stmt , 'bind_param' ) , $params );
```